# Weight of lowest common ancestor satisfies strong triangle inequality

Tags: trees, binary-trees

How do I prove that $d(x,y)$, defined as the weight of the lowest common ancestor of $x,y$, satisfies the strong triangle inequality:

$$ d(x,y) \le \max(d(x,z), d(y,z)) $$

How do I even start such a proof?

Comment: Start by trying some examples.  Then you'll probably realize that there is a case analysis based on the relative locations of their LCAs.  Try all cases.

Comment: How is the weight of a node defined?